# How To pass different set of data to different child views inside ContainerView

Tags: ember.js

**ContainerCode:**

```
ViewsContainer = emberextensions.Views.ContainerView.extend({                
    setupContainer: function () {
        this.setObjects([]);
        var controller = this.get('controller');
        $.each(controller.get('content'), $.proxy(function (index, val) {
            //asdfsadf/
            if (val.ProductType === "v1") {
                this.pushObject(v1.create()
                    ),
            if (val.ProductType === "v2") {
                this.pushObject(v2.create()
                    ),                        
            }));
            }
        }, this));
    }.observes('controller.content.@each'),
});
```

I want to pass different set of data to different views in container. I have crated a container view and trying to push child views on basis of certain conditions.every view has a different set of data. whole data is with the appcontroller how to pass different set of data to different child views inside container view